# pyqtgraph график не отображается в окне приложения

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, график, pyqtgraph

Создаю приложение, в котором при нажатии на кнопку "Построить график" будет строиться многоугольник по введенным координатам.

В функции `def postroy(self)` описываю подсчет площади и построение графика. После нажатия на кнопку функция выполняется, площадь посчитывается, но поле графика остается пустым.

Что я делаю не так?

Код основного файла:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

from mydesign import Ui_MainWindow  # Это наш конвертированный файл дизайна
import sys  # sys нужен для передачи argv в QApplication
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg


# Второе окно, которое открывается при ошибке ввода данных
class AnalystWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Ошибка ввода")  # Заголовок окна приложения
        self.setObjectName('MainWindow')
        self.setStyleSheet("""#MainWindow {background-color: #ffffff;} """)  # Изменение цвета фона на белый

        self.resize(330, 250)  # Изменение размера окна
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)  # Добавление виджета QLabel на форму приложения
        self.label.setText("Вы ввели неверные данные.")  # Изменение текста для QLabel

        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 250,
                                            50))  # Изменение местоположения элемента Qlabel (координаты слева, координаты сверху, ширина QLabel, высота QLabel)
        self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times New Roman', 14))  # Изменение шрифта и размера текста для Qlabel
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)  # Добавление виджета QLabel на форму приложения
        self.label1.setText("Повторите ввод.")  # Изменение текста для QLabel

        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 250,
                                             50))  # Изменение местоположения элемента Qlabel (координаты слева, координаты сверху, ширина QLabel, высота QLabel)
        self.label1.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times New Roman', 14))  # Изменение шрифта и размера текста для Qlabel


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.postroy)  # Действие кнопки "Построить график
        # Выполнить функцию postroy

    def postroy(self):

        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        x0 = self.lineEdit.text()  # считываем текст с lineEdit
        y0 = self.lineEdit_2.text()  # считываем текст с lineEdit_2
        x = x0.split()  # преобазовываем в массив
        y = y0.split()
        xsize = np.size(x)  # считаем размеры
        ysize = np.size(y)

        if xsize == ysize:
            size = xsize
        else:
            self.secondWin = AnalystWindow(self)
            self.secondWin.show()  # Открытие нового окна, описание которого дано в классе AnalystWindow
            return

        try:
            for i in range(size):  # проверка типа данных
                x[i] = float(x[i])
                y[i] = float(y[i])
        except ValueError:
            self.secondWin = AnalystWindow(self)
            self.secondWin.show()  # Открытие нового окна, описание которого дано в классе AnalystWindow
            return

        for i in range(size):  # переводим в тип float
            x[i] = float(x[i])
            y[i] = float(y[i])

        x.append(x[0])  # замыкаем ломанную
        y.append(y[0])

        ploshad = 0
        for i in range(size):
            ploshad += abs(x[i] * y[i + 1] - x[i + 1] * y[i]) / 2  # считаем площадь

        self.GraphWidget.plot(x, y, clear=True) #!!!!Вот эта штука не работает!!!!

        print(x)
        print(y)
        print(ploshad)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

На всякий случай файл дизайна с QtDesigner

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(782, 532)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 10, 231, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS PGothic")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 731, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLiU-ExtB")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.GraphWidget = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.GraphWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(29, 89, 341, 351))
        self.GraphWidget.setObjectName("GraphWidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 120, 351, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 400, 111, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 400, 91, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 90, 281, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 150, 281, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 180, 351, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 460, 111, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 460, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 460, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 220, 351, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 300, 351, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 330, 351, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 370, 281, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 270, 201, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 782, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Привет, Математик!"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Данное приложение поможет тебе построить многоугольник по заданным координатам, и подсчитать его площадь"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Цвет фигуры"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите данные координаты x  вершин"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите данные координаты y  вершин"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить, как:"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PNG"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PDF"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Построить график"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить подпись"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Измените цвет вашего многоугольника"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавьте название графика"))
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы перестарались с загрузкой формы в приложение. Я отметил для вас строки, которые лишние. Пробуйте:

```
import sys  
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
#import pyqtgraph as pg


#from mydesign import Ui_MainWindow  
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(782, 532)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 10, 231, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS PGothic")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 731, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLiU-ExtB")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.GraphWidget = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.GraphWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(29, 89, 341, 351))
        self.GraphWidget.setObjectName("GraphWidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 120, 351, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 400, 111, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 400, 91, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 90, 281, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 150, 281, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 180, 351, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 460, 111, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 460, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 460, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 220, 351, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 300, 351, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 330, 351, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 370, 281, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 270, 201, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 782, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Привет, Математик!"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Данное приложение поможет тебе построить многоугольник по заданным координатам, и подсчитать его площадь"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Цвет фигуры"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите данные координаты x  вершин"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите данные координаты y  вершин"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить, как:"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PNG"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PDF"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Построить график"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить подпись"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Измените цвет вашего многоугольника"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавьте название графика"))
# from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget


# Второе окно, которое открывается при ошибке ввода данных
class AnalystWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AnalystWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Ошибка ввода")  
        self.setObjectName('MainWindow')
        self.setStyleSheet("""#MainWindow {background-color: #ffffff;} """)  # Изменение цвета фона на белый

        self.resize(330, 250)                            # Изменение размера окна
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)              # Добавление виджета QLabel на форму приложения
        self.label.setText("Вы ввели неверные данные.")  # Изменение текста для QLabel

        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(
            20, 10, 250, 50))  # Изменение местоположения элемента Qlabel (координаты слева, координаты сверху, ширина QLabel, высота QLabel)
        self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times New Roman', 14))  # Изменение шрифта и размера текста для Qlabel
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)      # Добавление виджета QLabel на форму приложения
        self.label1.setText("Повторите ввод.")    # Изменение текста для QLabel

        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(
            20, 30, 250, 50))  # Изменение местоположения элемента Qlabel (координаты слева, координаты сверху, ширина QLabel, высота QLabel)
        self.label1.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times New Roman', 14))  # Изменение шрифта и размера текста для Qlabel


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        
#        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()                                          # --- нет
#        self.ui.setupUi(self)                                              # --- нет

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.postroy)  

    def postroy(self):
#        self.ui.setupUi(self)                                              # --- нет
        x0 = self.lineEdit.text()    # считываем текст с lineEdit
        y0 = self.lineEdit_2.text()  # считываем текст с lineEdit_2
        x = x0.split()               # преобазовываем в массив
        y = y0.split()
        xsize = np.size(x)           # считаем размеры
        ysize = np.size(y)

        if xsize == ysize:
            size = xsize
        else:
            self.secondWin = AnalystWindow(self)
            self.secondWin.show()    # Открытие нового окна, описание которого дано в классе AnalystWindow
            return

        try:
            for i in range(size):    # проверка типа данных
                x[i] = float(x[i])
                y[i] = float(y[i])
        except ValueError:
            self.secondWin = AnalystWindow(self)
            self.secondWin.show()    # Открытие нового окна, описание которого дано в классе AnalystWindow
            return

        for i in range(size):        # переводим в тип float
            x[i] = float(x[i])
            y[i] = float(y[i])

        x.append(x[0])               # замыкаем ломанную
        y.append(y[0])

        ploshad = 0
        for i in range(size):
            ploshad += abs(x[i] * y[i + 1] - x[i + 1] * y[i]) / 2  # считаем площадь

        self.GraphWidget.plot(x, y, clear=True)                    # ! Вот эта штука не работает !

        print(x)
        print(y)
        print(ploshad)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = MyWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @daveroom  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour